# problem with the url on the server with js A+

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Creating my web application, on behalf of the server, it tells me that there is an error on the part of mongoose, line 20 A+ /Being able to have a route with which the environment is compatible and that the route is free when class changes Take into account corrections and routes within class calls. . Has anyone had a problem with the routes to create the environment in Express?. I hope to solve the problem in order to make the url work in my project for my Harvard University, I would appreciate your help

````
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const TasasDeCambio = require('./server/models/TasasDeCambio');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tasasDeCambio', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Conexión exitosa a la base de datos");    
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('No se pudo conectar a la base de datos. Saliendo...', err);
    process.exit();
});

app.post('/tasasDeCambio', (req, res) => {

    const tasaDeCambio = new TasasDeCambio({
        moneda: req.body.moneda,
        tasa: req.body.tasa
    });

    tasaDeCambio.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Ocurrió un error al crear la tasa de cambio."
        });
    });
});

app.get('/tasasDeCambio', (req, res) => {
    TasasDeCambio.find()
    .then(tasasDeCambio => {
        res.send(tasasDeCambio);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Ocurrió un error al obtener las tasas de cambio."
        });
    });
});

app.put('/tasasDeCambio/:tasaId', (req, res) => {

    TasasDeCambio.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.tasaId, {
        moneda: req.body.moneda,
        tasa: req.body.tasa
    }, {new: true})
    .then(tasaDeCambio => {
        if(!tasaDeCambio) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "No se encontró una tasa de cambio con el id " + req.params.tasaId
            });
        }
        res.send(tasaDeCambio);
    }).catch(err => {
        if(err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "No se encontró una tasa de cambio con el id " + req.params.tasaId
            });                
        }
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Ocurrió un error al actualizar la tasa de cambio con el id " + req.params.tasaId
        });
    });
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try first structure the B+ functions inside the server without omitting the classes - In this case, try checking the other routes or what you inherited in your main.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  obtenerTasasDeCambio();
    
  document.getElementById('crear').addEventListener('click', crearTasaDeCambio);
};

function obtenerTasasDeCambio() {
  fetch('/tasasDeCambio')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => mostrarTasasDeCambio(data))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
    
function mostrarTasasDeCambio(tasasDeCambio) {
  let tabla = document.getElementById('tablaTasasDeCambio');
  tasasDeCambio.forEach(tasa => {
    let fila = tabla.insertRow();
    let celdaMoneda = fila.insertCell();
    let celdaTasa = fila.insertCell();
    let celdaAcciones = fila.insertCell();
    celdaMoneda.textContent = tasa.moneda; 
    
    let entradaTasa = document.createElement('input');
    entradaTasa.type = 'number';
    entradaTasa.value = tasa.tasa;
    entradaTasa.id = 'tasa-' + tasa._id;
    celdaTasa.appendChild(entradaTasa);
    
    let botonActualizar = document.createElement('button');
    botonActualizar.textContent = 'Actualizar';
    botonActualizar.addEventListener('click', function() {
      actualizarTasaDeCambio(tasa.id);
    });
    
    let botonBorrar = document.createElement('button');
    botonBorrar.textContent = 'Borrar';
    botonBorrar.addEventListener('click', function() {
      borrarTasaDeCambio(tasa._id);
    });
                
    celdaAcciones.appendChild(botonActualizar);
    celdaAcciones.appendChild(botonBorrar);
  });
}
```